# How can i delete modules' .so files in x86 or x86_64. Such as modify the build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, .so

If i use the Android Studio compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+',
How can i delete their .so files in x86 or x86_64. 
Such as modify the build.gradle.
Because my app don't need to support WindowsPhone platform.
And i need my app's size as small as possible.

Comment: x86 and x86_64 are not there for Windows phone, but for Intel based Android devices. You should not delete them.

Comment: 3q for r help. i mean compare with support x86 devices, i prefer care my app's size. i dont know how to use gradle modify some files such as delete them before generate the final apk. i can do that when i use Ant but I do not know how to use gradle do that...